# RSpec it_behaves_like reduces debugging visibility

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have the following code:

```
context 'user doesnt exists with that email' do
  let(:params) { original_params.merge(login: "nouser@example.org") }
  it_behaves_like '404'
  it_behaves_like 'json result'
  it_behaves_like 'auditable created'
end
```

It is dry because I can use these elements in other contexts as well:

```
context 'user exists with that email' do
  it_behaves_like '200'
  it_behaves_like 'json result'
end
```

My shared_example is:

```
...
RSpec.shared_examples "json result" do
  specify 'returns JSON' do
    api_call params, developer_header
    expect { JSON.parse(response.body) }.not_to raise_error
  end
end
...
```

The benefits are that the spec is more readable and is dry. The spec failure points to the shared_example file rather than the original spec. It is hard to debug.
The following error occurs at login_api_spec:25, but this is rspecs output:

```
rspec ./spec/support/shared_examples/common_returns.rb:14 # /api/login GET /email user doesnt exists with that email behaves like 401 returns 401
```

Any good advice how to proceed to write both dry and easy to debug rspec?

Without shared examples the code would be much longer and not as easy to read:

```
context 'user doesnt exists with that email' do
  let(:params) { original_params.merge(login: "nouser@example.org") }
  specify "returns 404" do
    api_call params, developer_header
    expect(response.status).to eq(404)
  end
  specify 'returns JSON' do
    api_call params, developer_header
    expect { JSON.parse(response.body) }.not_to raise_error
  end
  specify 'creates an api call audit' do
    expect do
      api_call params, developer_header
    end.to change{ EncoreBackend::ApiCallAudit.count }.by(1)
  end
end
```

I have thousands of RSpec tests like this so it is very beneficial to write the specs with shared examples because it is fast to write, but the debugging is hard.

Answer (score 2):

Amongst the detailed errors there is description like this:

```
Shared Example Group: "restricted_for developers" called from ./spec/api/login_api_spec.rb:194
```

This tells the exact place of the error